# Visual Studio C++/CLI Syntax Error when using .Net Windows Form

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli

I have the following code and Visual Studio C++ reports two errors:

```
#include "windows.h"

#using <mscorlib.dll>

#using <System.dll>

#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

__gc class MyForm : public Form

{

public: 

MyForm()

 { 

     Text = "Hello, Windows Forms!";

     Button* button = new Button();

     button->Text = "Click Me!";

     button->Click += new EventHandler(this, button_click);

     this->Controls->Add(button);

}

void button_click(Object* sender, EventArgs* e)

{

MessageBox::Show("Ouch!");

}

};

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)

{

Application::Run(new MyForm);

}
```

and the errors:
error C2061 Syntax Error: Event Args
error C2061 Syntax Error: EventHandler

What should I do to get the code running ?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Changed your tag, don't tag a question for Managed C++ as "C++" - that is a completely different language. What I see is that you forgot a `using namespace System`. But you should really consider to use C++/CLI instead (or C#), Managed C++ is deprecated.

Comment: you don't need a `WinMain` for Windows Forms. You can just use a `main` too.

Comment: I found the problem, check the edit.

Comment: @ Doc Brown: I am actually using C++ / CLI not Managed C++

Comment: @MarcusTik: so why didn't you mention that in your question? ;) I added it in the title and tags for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line 'using namespace System;'

```
    using namespace System;
```

Change ref to button_click as: &MyForm::button_click

Full working code:

```
    #include "windows.h" 

    #using <mscorlib.dll> 
    #using <System.dll> 
    #using <System.Windows.Forms.dll> 

    using namespace System::Windows::Forms; 
    using namespace System;

    __gc class MyForm : public Form 
    { 

        public: 

        MyForm() 
        {  

             Text = "Hello, Windows Forms!"; 

             Button* button = new Button();  
             button->Text = "Click Me!"; 

             button->Click += new EventHandler(this, &MyForm::button_click); 

             this->Controls->Add(button);  
        } 

        void button_click(Object* sender, EventArgs* e) 
        { 
            MessageBox::Show("Ouch!"); 
        } 

    }; 

    int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)  
    { 
      Application::Run(new MyForm);  
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that you didn't add:

```
using namespace System;
```

Since `EventArgs` and `EventHandler` are both in the *System* namespace, you must either declare them as,

```
new System::EventHandler()
System::EventArgs* 
...
```

or include the `using` statement above.

However, there are a few other problems as well.

- Firstly, there is no need to include `windows.h`, that is only needed if you are calling native Windows Api functions.
- Secondly, you don't need a `WinMain` for managed-c++ windows forms, a simple `main` function will do.
- Thirdly, why the `CALLBACK` before `WinMain`?, it's generally preceded by an `APIENTRY` or a `WINAPI`.

Comment: The `CALLBACK`, `APIENTRY`, and `WINAPI` macros are all defined to the same thing, so this is not actually affecting the operation of the program. But yes, semantically, it would be more clear to use something else.